# summaryStatistics Method of IntSummaryStatistics

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Why summaryStatistics() method on an empty IntStream returns max and min value of integer as the maximum and minimum int value present in the stream?

```
IntStream intStream = IntStream.of();
IntSummaryStatistics stat = intStream.summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(stat);
```

**Output**:

```
IntSummaryStatistics{count=0, sum=0, min=2147483647, average=0.000000, max=-2147483648}
```

1. What is the point of returning these values?
2. Should not it considered the wrong result?

Comment: what's the minimum of an empty set? I'd say no value would be correct in that case.

Comment: What is wrong with that? That's how they decided to represent "unknown" values

Comment: Not to forget that `IntStream`  and `IntConsumer` (extended by `IntSummaryStatistics`) deals with primitive `int` and that if in some way an `Optional<Integer>` was to be returned from `getMin()`, it would be contradictory to the reason what the API was designed for(the specialization). On the other hand, there is a way you out, you can create your own `IntegerSummaryStatistics` based on the conditions that you might want to implement as a custom logic around Integer values. But decide wisely, if it is worth it.

Answer (score 4):

See [IntSummaryStatistics.getMax()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#getMax--) and [IntSummaryStatistics.getMin()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#getMin--) docs, this exact behaviour is described there, when no values are recorded.

It is just sensible to return these in these corner cases.
I will just explain this behaviour `IntSummaryStatistics.getMin()` here.

Example: Let us just say the list contains at least one entry. Whatever the integer value is for that entry, it is not going to be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So returning this value when there are no entries makes sense, to give an insight to the user.

Same goes for `IntSummaryStatistics.getMax()`

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is documented in the Javadoc, so that's the correct behavior by definition:

> **int java.util.IntSummaryStatistics.getMin()**
>
> Returns the minimum value recorded, or Integer.MAX_VALUE if no values have been recorded.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the minimum value, or Integer.MAX_VALUE if none

and

> **int java.util.IntSummaryStatistics.getMax()**
>
> Returns the maximum value recorded, or Integer.MIN_VALUE if no values have been recorded.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the maximum value, or Integer.MIN_VALUE if none

As to "what's the point of returning these values", we can argue that the minimum value of an empty `Stream` should be such that if the `Stream` had any element, that element would be smaller than that value.

Similarly, we can argue that the maximum value of an empty `Stream` should be such that if the `Stream` had any element, that element would be larger than that value.

Answer (score 1):

To find a `minimum int` value in any array you typically initialize the default to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i : somearray) {
   if (i < min) {
     min = i;
   }
}

return min;
```

So if there was nothing to iterate, the value of the default `min` would be returned.  For
max, the default `max` is initialized to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is empty and those methods return an actual value and not an `Optional<Integer>` it assumes the full Integer range. Otherwise it would return an empty `Optional<Integer>`.